# How to connecting two ADXL345 (GY-291 modules) to one Arduino UNO R3 by using pin jumper?

Tags: wiring, breadboard, accelerometer, arduino-uno

I am having some trouble in connecting two independent [ADXL345](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/adxl345.pdf) ([GY-291](http://wiki.sunfounder.cc/index.php?title=ADXL345_3-Axis_Digital_Acceleration_of_Gravity_Tilt_Module_(GY-291)) modules) to my one [Arduino UNO R3](https://docs.arduino.cc/resources/datasheets/A000066-datasheet.pdf). Before this I tried using one ADXL345 and it works perfectly, but in my project I need to use two ADXL345 connected to an Arduino UNO R3.

How do I connect the wires of both ADXL345 to the UNO?

How should I wire the SDA pin, SDO pin, VCC pin, SCL pin, VCC pin and other pins as well?

I asked on the [Adafruit forum](https://forums.adafruit.com/viewtopic.php?t=204127) but I didn't understand the reply.

[image: image of ADXL345 and Arduino UNO]

[image: real image of ADXL345 and Arduino UNO]

Comment: @Airidz - Hi, Now that you have edited the question to add more details of where you are stuck, I have expedited the reopening of the question to allow site members another opportunity to answer it. I also found & added a link to the (claimed) schematic of the generic GY-291 modules you have, as well as other links which I copied over from your duplicate question. The answer on the Adafruit forum is already good, but it seems you need more detailed help.

Comment: @SamGibson - Hi, thank you so much for helping me.  I admit that the answer on the Adafruit forum is good but maybe I still need more details or steps on how to connect the wire one by one. Anyways thank you for helping me this much. I really appreciate you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to connect the SDA, SCL, VCC, GND pins in a daisy chain from the UNO i.e. VCC UNO -> VCC MOD1 -> VCC MOD2.

On one of the modules you must then pull up SDO to VCC with a 1K resistor.  This will cause it to use its alternative I2C address.  Unless you do this, the two module will both use the same default address, and your system will not work.

Comment: I see, thanks for the suggestion. I will try it.  Is it necessary to use the resistor or not because I had seen other people that do not use the resistor but it seem there add another jumper wire to change the address.

Comment: You could just wire to VCC, but I tend to use pull-up resistors to avoid any possible latch-up problems at power up.  However, this is probably just me being overly cautious!

Comment: I get that. Thank for the recommendations. I will update if there any outcome from it.